# Colors are opposite of what they should be on iPad

Tags: ipad

I have an original **iPad**.

I have noticed that certain sites/documents display in the opposite colors they should--a white background is black, a red image is green, a blue image is yellow.Now I have created a masthead in Photoshop using white, blue and green.  It is a jpeg if that makes any difference.
On all of my devices it displays properly except on the iPad where it displays as black, gold, and purple--and totally clashes with everything else.

This is the [site](http://www.reformSbCounty.com), if that helps--sorry I can't seem to insert it as a hyperlink.  It is only a temp site, so this is not earth shattering, but I would like to know how to prevent this for future sites.

Comment: On my original iPad your site renders correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The image http://reformsbcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ReformHeader-copy2.jpg is using a CMYK colorspace.  You should try to use a RGB colorspace for the web (24bit image). There is a fuss about JPEG CMYK color bytes which are stored inverted by PhotoShop (adding a special marker that not all JPEG consumers interpret) . 0% color is stored as 0xFF (and 100% as 0x00) while the standard is 0->0 100%->0xFF.  So try converting your images as RGB images should give you a correct rendering on all devices.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That makes sense.  I didn't know what to look for in Photoshop to change but knew someone would.